How do i solve "error: package com.dooboolab.RNIap does not exist" for Android?
I am using React Native and the package react-native-iap for handling in-app purchases. I needed to upgrade the package to be able too meet the the latest requirements from Google to use Google Play Billing Library version 6.0.1 or later. I have upgraded the package to 12.15.2, and it works on iOS. But when I am trying to build the app on android I get:
"error: package com.dooboolab.RNIap does not exist
import com.dooboolab.RNIap.RNIapPackage;"
It seems like the the path for the package has changed from com.dooboolab.RNIap to com.dooboolab.rniap, but in the PackageList.java it auto generates the path com.dooboolab.RNIap. How do i solve this issue?
I've tried to manually import the package in MainApplication.kt, but the wrong path is still auto generating when i'm building for Android. So the error is still there.
Also tried downgrading the package to 11.x.x and then it works, but as I understand it the package needs to be at version ^12.x.x to be able to use Google Play Billing Library version 6 or higher.
